# Using shiny to highlight specific bar in a bar chart

Tags: r, shiny

I am not sure if Im doing this the right way (I am open for suggestions!). However what I try to do if to create a Shiny app where i can pick a bar and then the bar should be highlighted in the graph.

For this example I use the titanic_train dataset.

I do:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)

UI <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("specific_bar", "Pick bar to highlight:",
                  choices = unique(titanic_train$Embarked))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot_nice")
    )
  )
)


Server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered <- reactive({
    titanic_train$Specific <- ifelse((titanic_train$Embarked == input$specific_bar), 1,0)
  })

  output$plot_nice <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered(), aes_string(x="Embarked", y="Survived", fill = "Specific")) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

Running this however gives me the following error:

```
ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

And the problem really seems to have to do with the filtered() reactive function. Any thoughts on what  is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to ask for the data.frame object back in the reactive part,
what you were doing is getting a vector back instead of getting another column added to *titanic_train*.
this should fix it:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(titanic)
library(dplyr)

UI <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("specific_bar", "Pick bar to highlight:",
                  choices = unique(titanic_train$Embarked))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot_nice")
    )
  )
)


Server <- function(input, output) {

  filtered <- reactive({
    titanic_train$Specific <- ifelse((titanic_train$Embarked == input$specific_bar), 1,0)
    return(titanic_train)
  })

  output$plot_nice <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(filtered(), aes_string(x="Embarked", y="Survived", fill = "Specific")) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```